# Using file with json data as database

Tags: php, json, filesystems

I'm writing a small program that does just one task, stores phone numbers that need to be returned,
And my goal is to use a single Json file as the database. Now here is my problem, since I want all employees to have access to this program I can't use PHP's json_decode and _encode functions and then use fwrite() because then one employee will be overriding another. So my question is if their is any workaround for this or if someone can suggest a library that would handle this.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) ? This should perfectly fit your needs

Comment: @hek2mgl yes but I'm doing this for fun too, so I'm playing around a little

Comment: If you must store everything in a single file, you'll have to use some locking mechanism to ensure two people are not editing / writing concurrently.

Comment: Why not use sqlite? It's a database in a file

Comment: Some times the problem itself should be changed instead to looking for non reasonable solution, personally, I will not prefer you to continue using this idea.

Comment: this is not software engineering..this is just a bad way to use tools in the way they are not born/made for. So as people yet suggested to you, use sqlite or mongodb or even better just share a document with this numbers (like google docs..)

Comment: It's pretty hard to arbitrarily say this is a bad idea.  Depending on the application it could make sense, if nothing else it will be a good learning experience for OP.  You never know, OP may *realize* it wasn't the best approach, but end up learning about mutexes in the meantime; how bad could that be?

Comment: @quickshiftin, That's right as I mentioned in my first comment, I'm doing this for fun too(sharpening my skills)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this by creating a mutex.  If you're on Windows, I'd suggest [flock](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php), but if you're on *nix, I'd suggest a [sys5 semaphore](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php).

As an aside, if you want a much hackier/simpler setup, you can pump the output from `json_encode` through [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php), as it implements its own mutex.

Another option which is probably easier would be to use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).